# Notice: Array to string conversion - PHP & mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've been reading in every thread in here that is related to this but I always get it wrong.

Please help cause I always get the error

> "Notice: Array to string conversion" in line "$address[] =
>   mysql_result($row, 0 );"

below. Please help.

```
if ($p_address=mysql_query($email))
{
$address = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($p_address))
{     
 $address[] = mysql_result($row, 0 );
}  

$all_address = implode(',', $address);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line

```
 $address[] = mysql_result($row, 0 );
```

To this:

```
 $address[] = $row;
```

And then to see the keys and values available in the new `$address` array, you can do something like this:

```
 print_r($address);
```

In order to keep `implode()` functional, do something like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($address); $i++) {
  $all_address[] = implode(',', $address[$i]);
}
```

Final output:

```
if ($p_address=mysql_query($email))
{
$address = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($p_address))
{     
 $address[] = $row;
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($address); $i++) {
  $all_address[] = implode(',', $address[$i]);
}

// Example for outputting on screen:
foreach ($all_address as $aa) {
  print $aa . "<br/>\n";
}
}
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: It gives the same error. Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\admission\main_admin\announce_email.php on line 468
Array,Array,Array

Comment: I think you missed a comma in implode(',' $address[$i]). Yet, it has another error: Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in $all_address[] = implode(',' $address[$i]);

Comment: OMG. It works. But I have another problem. And it's in the mail function.

Comment: Fixed. Regarding *I have another problem. And it's in the mail function.*, I think you'll have to post another question to make sure everything stays on topic, relative to the topic on hand... Ya know?

Comment: Yeah that's my plan, to post another question. I think it's a little bit irrelevant in this thread. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$row is set in every iteration of the while loop. every time it contains a new table record. So you just need to add each record in the address array.

```
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($p_address))
   {     
      $address[] = $row;
   }
```

Comment: It gives the same error. Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\admission\main_admin\announce_email.php on line 468 Array,Array,Array

Comment: what is the query you are sending? do a var_dump($row) to see what comes

Comment: I believe you mean $row[column]. Else the whole resultset-array would be appended to the $adress-array in each iteration.

Comment: I am retrieving email address from the database all at once, and send them messages through mail function.

Comment: then try $address[] = $row[0] or $row[column name]; depending on your query