# error when attempt to store image urls in database

Tags: php

I have the following code to store array content (image urls) on specific column in database

```
// store the values returned by getItemImageUrls() in the sqlite DB
     foreach ($items as $item) {
                             $images = $item-> getItemImageUrls(); 
                            $db->table('images')->save(array(
                            'items_id' => $item->getId(), //Item class filed
                             'link' =>$images  // store Urls into link column of images table
                             ));
                        }
```

the `getItemImages()` is a function to retrieve image urls from html string as follows:

```
 public function getItemImageUrls()
    {
        $dom = new domDocument;
        $dom->loadHTML($this->content);
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $url = array();
        $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
        foreach($images as $img)
        {
            $url[] = $img->getAttribute('src');
        }

        return  ($url);
    }
```

my problem here is that iam getting Array to string conversion error. how can i fix this?
appreciate your help

Comment: Where is the actual query? This isn't enough to solve your problem

Comment: You are trying to insert a php array to the database. If you want to insert _all_ of the image urls in the same column you should convert them into a string (say json, comma-separated, etc)

Comment: array returns several number of strings let's say 10 urls,i want to store each url in a separate row

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notice: Array to string conversion - PHP & mySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387485/notice-array-to-string-conversion-php-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is **your database column don't accept array but only a string**. So we need to convert the images array using the [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function,into a comma seperated string .

*updated the code to save each row separately*

```
// store the values returned by getItemImageUrls() in the sqlite DB
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $images = $item-> getItemImageUrls();

    //converting the array into string (update : you don't need it )
    //$images = implode(",", $images); 

    //update : for saving each image in single row
    foreach($images as $image) {
           $db->table('images')->save(array(
             'items_id' => $item->getId(), //Item class filed
             'link' =>$image  // store Urls into link column of images table
             ));
    }

}
```

you can convert back the string into array using  [explode](http://php.net/explode) function when you need it.

Comment: I have tried your code but it stores all the image urls on single row.. in fact i want each url to be stored on single row. means one row for each url returned by array.

Comment: @user2198400 now each image will be saved in separate rows

Comment: i have done something similar to your suggestion and it works  $images = $item-> getItemImageUrls();
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($images); $i++) {
                        $db->table('images')->save(array(
                        'items_id' => $item->getId(), //Item class filed
                        'link' => $images[$i]
                    ));
                }