# I got Error Notice: Array to string conversion in my code php

Tags: php

hi guys i got problem in my code 
i don't know where come form this my code

```
<h1><?php echo $item["title"]; ?> </h1>
       <table>
          <tr>
             <th>Catageory</th>
             <td><?php echo $item["category"]; ?></td>
         </tr> 
         <tr>
             <th>Genre</th>
             <td><?php echo $item["genre"]; ?></td>
         </tr> 
         <tr>
             <th>Format</th>
             <td><?php echo $item["format"]; ?></td>
         </tr> 
         <tr>
             <th>Year</th>
             <td><?php echo $item["year"]; ?></td>
         </tr> 
         <?php
         if(strtolower($item["category"]) == "books"){
             ?>
        <tr>
             <th>Authors</th>
             <td><?php echo $item["authors"]; ?></td>
         </tr> 

        <tr>
             <th>Publisher</th>
             <td><?php echo $item["publisher"]; ?></td>
         </tr> 
        <tr>
             <th>ISBN</th>
             <td><?php echo $item["isbn"]; ?></td>
         </tr>           

    <?php    }  ?>
```

And the error message,

[image]

and Iam sure all code are same i don't what's problem !!

Comment: can i see the query ?

Comment: What is "$item" exactly? Something you fetch from MySQL? If so, do rows like "year", "publisher", among others exist there? And if so, what is the query you try to execute?

Comment: show the query as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notice: Array to string conversion - PHP & mySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387485/notice-array-to-string-conversion-php-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my problem is solved

by replace

```
             <td><?php echo $item["authors"]; ?></td>
```

to

```
<td><?php echo implode(",", $item["authors"]); ?></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As per your image, you are trying to print string on line 58, but you are getting array from your resultant query. So try to var_dump($yourvar) and check that are you **getting required string or an array**

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to echo an array variable which is not right. Use the below debug code and you have to parse the array however you want.

```
    Authors ->  <?php echo "<pre>";print_r($item["authors"]);echo "<pre>"; ?>
```